# Constrain to 50% from top of ImageView

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout like so:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic[1]" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Basically, the `View` is overlaying on top of the `ImageView`. However, I need the top of the `View` to start at the middle point of the `ImageView`, i.e. 50% from the top of the `ImageView`. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you try layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" ?

Comment: Doesn't change anything. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: use Guideline for that

Answer (score 3):

Percentage constraints in `ConstraintLayout` only work in relationship to the parent of a view. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#DimensionConstraints). There is, however, the concept of "weighted chains" for widgets that have `match_constraints`. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#Chains).

> **Weighted chains**
>
> The default behavior of a chain is to spread the elements equally in the available space. If one or more elements are using MATCH_CONSTRAINT, they will use the available empty space (equally divided among themselves). The attribute layout_constraintHorizontal_weight and layout_constraintVertical_weight will control how the space will be distributed among the elements using MATCH_CONSTRAINT. For exemple, on a chain containing two elements using MATCH_CONSTRAINT, with the first element using a weight of 2 and the second a weight of 1, the space occupied by the first element will be twice that of the second element.

So, your XML should look something like below for this result. (I have colored the background of the `View` so it can be seen.

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic[1]" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `ImageView` is a square, you can use the dimension ratio attribute here too. Remove the top constraint of the `View` to make it align to the bottom and set the width:height ratio to `H,2:1` to constrain height based on width.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView4" />
```